# click event not producing the expected result

Tags: javascript

I have this code that looks clean and fine, but it is not producing the desired result.
**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
    <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
    <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
    <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
    <a href="#" class="ankor" >justklick</a>
  </div>       
</nav>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function click(ev) {
        var ev = window.event;
        console.log(ev.type);
    }
    var anchor = document.querySelector('.ankor');
    anchor.onClick = click();
```

I actually expected to see the name of the event in my console, instead this is what i am having as the result   "DOMContentLoaded".

Can anybody tell me a reason for this?

Comment: You have a typo. Your doc.ready function isn't closed properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By appending `()` you are executing `click` immediately inside your `jQuery(document).ready(function () {`  Inside this block, you are assigning `var ev = window.event` which is what you see when you console/log: `DomContentLoaded` is the window event, as execution is inside the document/ready block.

One way to avoid your problem is to substitute the following:

```
anchor.onClick = click();
```

With the following which only executes on click, instead of immediately:

```
$(anchor).on('click', click);
```

Comment: Thanks George, I thought my code was clean. and i dont want to use the easy jquery throughtout.

Comment: @pedroyanky Don't get caught up on the fact that I used jQuery.  The issues are 1) you immediately call click() and 2) where you call click(), the window.event *is* DomContentLoaded

Answer (score 2):

> I actually expected to see the name of the event in my console,
>   instead this is what i am having as the result "DOMContentLoaded".
>
> Can anybody tell me a reason for this?

This happens due to the following line:

```
 var ev = window.event;
```

and the fact that you call the `click`

```
 anchor.onClick = click();
```

When you script would be parsed and executed the DomContentLoaded event happens and this is why you see that you described.

If you wan't to use your approach then you have to make a few corrections. Please see the below script.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function click(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
    }
  
    // You should place here this code, because click is only visible 
    // in this scope.
    var anchor = document.querySelector('.ankor');
    anchor.onclick = click;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
    <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
    <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
    <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
    <a href="#" class="ankor" >justklick</a>
  </div>       
</nav>
```

**Otherwise**, you could achieve that you are looking for using the following snippet, in a more compact way:

```js
$(function(){

  $(".ankor").on("click", function(ev){
        console.log(ev.type);
  });
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <div class="div1">
        <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
        <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
        <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
        <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
        <a href="#" class="ankor" >justklick</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Since you load jquery and you use it for the Dom Ready event to attach an event handler, then it would be more natural to use jQuery to select elements from the DOM rather than using plain JavaScript. At least, this is my two cents.

Last but not least, it follows the plain JavaScript approach:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    var ankors = document.getElementsByClassName("ankor");
    if(ankors.length){
        ankors[0].addEventListener("click",function(event){
            console.log(event.type);
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<nav>
     <div class="div1">
        <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
        <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
        <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
        <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
        <a href="#" class="ankor" >justklick</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** This code `anchor.onClick = click();` you are not passing in any event into the called function `function click(ev)` so `ev` is undefined, Also `var ev = window.event;` this is you are assigning a window event which is `undefined` too.

I see you are using Jquery, The above script can be made simple as below.

```js
$(function() { //  shor hand for jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
  $('.ankor').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
    <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
    <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
    <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
    <a href="#" class="ankor">justklick</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```

**Edit:** from your comments `the reason for the ready function, is to avoid my selection returning null` you can better use `window.onload` which is equivalent to document ready.

```
window.onload = function(){
  alert("onload event is fired");
};
```

Comment: *your code var anchor = document.querySelector('.ankor'); is outside the document ready event.* -- its not, his code indentation was just bad

Comment: i know it can be simplify, but i dont want that. I want to use javascript, the reason for the ready function, is to avoid my selection returning null

Comment: @pedroyanky when you use `jQuery(document).ready(function () {` you are already using jquery.

Comment: but one can write a pure javascript code inside the jQuery function, but avoid the jQuery wrapper and still have results

Comment: @pedroyanky just adding a big chunk of jquery file just to use document ready is not any good on performance..

Comment: @pedroyanky anyways I am going to delete my answer.. you can use `window.onload` that suits best for you now..

Comment: I actually thought in events, when calling functions that takes events as argument, there is no need to pass in a parameters as by calling the function, the event that that the function is being hocked up to, provide the argument, correct me please if am wrong

Comment: better than `window.onload` or `jQuery(document).ready` is a simple `setTimeout(fn)` which will wait for the DOM to be parsed

Comment: @pedroyanky when you assign a callback for the click event you must declare the function with parameters.. if done so then Jquery will make sure to fill up those parameters else it will do nothing .. it's as good as parameterless function

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to get type of event (here Click i guess) something like

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class='ank'>Click</a>
```

and js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ank').click(function(event)
  {
    console.log(event.type);
  });
});
```

Should work...:D

**Edit:** you almost have the answer(still just gave edit to my post :D ;D) 
from your post you must have called the

```
var anchor =document.querySelector('.ankor');
    anchor.onClick = click();
```

within the `document.ready(function(){//here})` block..to get DOMContentLoaded Message...as you got the result, the reason for it being You have not assigned any event by `anchor.onclick=click();` instead you called it and assigned it to anchor.onclick...a simple `console.log(anchor.onclick)` would show that...Just in case for explicit binding of event you can use

```
 $('selector').on('eventtobind',function(){
//more code
});
```